# Selected files to push in github repo out of multiple committed changes

Tags: git, github

I have working on a story and I have added 3 files for the story. I have added and committed them in my local branch. Now, I need to push 2 files of them to remote repository with urgent priority. Is it possible to push only 2 of them to push in github repo?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear... Are you asking whether you can push only the files you committed?

Comment: Not exactly. Say, I have committed file1, file2 and file3. Now I want to push only file1 and file2. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git push` doesn't work with files. It pushes commits. You can't push half a commit, and you can't push a commit without pushing its ancestry. So, if you want to push changes to `file1` and `file2`, but not changes to `file3`, you need to make sure that:

- commits changing `file1` and `file2` do not change `file3`
- commits changing `file1` and `file2` do not have any commits changing `file3` in their ancestry.

If this is already the case, then you can push the relevant commit using e.g.

```
git push origin <commit-touching-file1-and-file2>:master
```

Otherwise, you will need to edit your local history before. [`git rebase -i`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) is a great tool for that, but beware that this is a complex and potentially dangerous tool. Read the documentation and make backups before you play with it.

As a relatively brute-force alternative to `git rebase -i`, you can also discard all your local history and make another one:

```
git reset origin/master  # assuming the remote branch is master and hasn't changed since you cloned
git add file1 file2
git commit -m "changes to file1 and file2 only"
git push
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. But the scenario is, I have created the branch and added those three new files in that branch. And did commit multiple times. But have not pushed it in github. So, is it possible to bring the repo to the checkout state, from where all three files will show like "Not yet added". From there I can again add and commit only file1 and file2 and push them.

Comment: As I wrote, if you already did some commits you'll need to edit your local history before you can push changes individually. There's a more brute-force approach based on `reset` that I'm adding as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you commit file1 and file2 first and and do another one for file3 then you could push file1 and file2, but if you have already already committed everything, you could do reset to your previous commit with `git reset HEAD^` and only add file1 and file2, then commit then push. then you can add file 3 if you want.